# How did Korath know where Peter Quill was heading?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

In the beginning of the movie, shortly after arriving back aboard the *Dark Aster*, Korath says to Ronan:

> We have discovered that Quill has an agreement to retrieve the orb for an intermediary known as the Broker.

How did Korath know that?  We saw literally the entire interaction between him and Quill—he figured out that Quill was affiliated with the Ravagers but that was it.

Comment: Spies, man. Contacts.

Comment: Because Quill's got a big mouth and can't shut up. He probably blabbed it to a half-dozen people while he was trying to score the night before.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possibilities here;

### The girl

Although the timelines don't tally, it's certainly possible that [Bereet](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Bereet) blabbed as soon as she arrived back on Xandar. This assumes that Quill didn't go straight to the Broker's shop and that there's a gap that we're not seeing.

### The Ravagers

For me, the most likely option is that one of Yondu's Ravager Clan buddies gave away/sold the information. They don't seem especially savoury people and quite a few of them really seem to hate Peter, even before he double-crossed them. They'd be more than happy to see him dead.

---

### The Call?

There's an interesting addition to Yondu and Peter's video-call that appears in film's junior novelisation (based on an earlier version of the script), but that *doesn't* appear in the finished film.

> *“You know, boss, I feel bad about this… but I’m not going to tell you
>   that.” Yondu’s face twisted in anger. **“I slaved this putting together
>   a deal with the Broker for the Orb!”***

It's quite plausible that the implication is that video-comms aren't especially secure and that Ronan's men intercepted it in transit. When they updated the scene (to remove mention of the Broker), they likely didn't bother to update the next scene where Ronan *magically* knows Peter's destination.

Comment: wasnt there an indication that the blue skinned brute that is part of the group gave a call to ronan  (while still drunk) in order to lure him tehre to kill him?

Comment: @Thomas - I don't remember that, but that would make an excellent answer if you can flesh it out.

Comment: I only know the brute said he summoned ronan. But he didn'T mention if he told anything about the broker (in the message) as far as I'm aware.  so not really an answer there to the broker part thus no really worth its own  answer I fear.

Comment: None of these are particularly convincing.  The call, too… we see the entirety of that as well and Yondu does not mention the Broker.  (I just re-watched that scene with subtitles enabled—all he says is "I slaved putting this deal together.")

Comment: @Bob - I've updated accordingly. I still remain convinced that his Ravager buddies sold him out. They hate his guts.